# Scaling non-default version of Google App Engine Backend

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a live app that uses Google App Engine (python) for the backend. The app is pointing https://my-app.appspot.com. Because the API has changed significantly, I've set up a new version of the backend, 'v2', and am pointing the new app to https://v2.my-app.appspot.com.

I see now in the docs, that for `min_idle_instances` it says `The minimum number of idle instances that App Engine should maintain for this version. Only applies to the default version of a module, since other versions are not expected to receive significant traffic`

The problem is that I was hoping to launch the new Android version before the iOS version, since iOS takes longer to go through their review process.

So, is there any other way to ensure scalability of the new version without making it the default version? If not, is there any way to route the old traffic to a non-default version?

Comment: I see I might be able to use `min_pending_latency` and `min_pending_latency`. The default min_pending_latency is 30ms, and the lowest is 10ms. What is the default for max_pending_latency? It says `automatic`. Should I assume that that is the max max_pending_latency (15s) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems I can solve this problem using modules, which I switched a lot of my code to anyways for this iteration.

Each module is capable of having its own default version. So, the first version of the app can still hit `https://my-app.appspot.com`, (and that will stay the default module and default version, with its own `min_idle_instances`). The second version of the app switches what was the default module to being the `api` module. So that version can hit `https://v2-dot-api-dot-my-app.appspot.com`, and v2 can be default version of the api module, with its own `min_idle_instances`